# How to prevent TypeScript Record<string, any> from sorting object properties to alphabetical order?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Desired output:

```
{
  "z": 123,
  "y": 123,
  "x": 123
}
```

Example

```
const myArray = ['z', 'y', 'x'];
const r: Record<string, any> = {};

for (propKey of myArray)
   r[propKey] = 123;
```

Output:

```
{
  "x": 123,
  "y": 123,
  "z": 123
}
```

Comment: The order of objects keys is not something you can really control and may vary from browser to browser. If you want ordered data, use an array not an object.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using a library that requires so.

Comment: @ColdCerberus you can try Map with iteration

Comment: @ColdCerberus When you say "_desired output_" can you be extremely literal and describe exactly what you mean? Where is this "output"? How is it being created? How is it being used? Why does property order matter? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps)

> Although the keys of an ordinary Object are ordered now, this was not
> always the case, and the order is complex. As a result, it's best not
> to rely on property order.

**Alternatives**

- Array
- [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), you can use map to iterate and its entries are ordered

Comment: This question was asked way in the past when I still did not fully understand how TS works, not realizing that the question at hand here is ultimately JS. Appreciate the reference here. You can edit  your answer to clearly state that we have no control over it and must not rely on it at the first place then I'll mark this as the accepted one. Thanks